# R: order of calculation

Tags: r

```
VN <- function(n,s,y){
   if (n < N){
      V <- 1/(1+r)*(ptil*VN(n+1,u*s,a*u*s+y)+qtil*VN(n+1,s*d, a*d*s+y))
      return(V)
   }
   if (n == N){
      return(max(c(0,y-K)))
   }  
}
VN(0,S0, a*S0)
```

How does R calculate this? Does R first calculate VN(1,u*s,a*u*s+y), VN(2,u*s,a*u*s+y), VN(3,u*s,a*u*s+y),... until VN(N,u*s,a*u*s+y) and then start with VN(2,d*s,a*d*s+y),...? Or what is the correct order for R to calculate this? Take for example N = 3.

Comment: There is no implicit repeat-until loop if that is what you are asking. You would need to use explicit control structures if that was your intent.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that R evaluates inside-to-out (lowest nested expression to highest nested expression), and left-to-right after that. If you're worried about things being evaluated in the wrong order, braces are the answer, since they separate the equation you're using into distinct expressions.

Comment: So it will first calculate VN(1,u*s,a*u*s+y) and VN(1,s*d, a*d*s+y) and then it goes to n = 2?

Comment: No. It won't "go" to anything the way you have written it.

Comment: @Anita with so many variables that aren't explained, it's hard to tell; I would recommend much more spacing to make the equation easier to read. I'm not sure what you mean by "then it goes to n = 2".

(Minor pedantry point; at the moment you only have return conditions for when n is less than or equal to N. You probably want to specify what happens in the event that n > N)